# Do not increment qty for same product in cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, qty

**Magento 2.4.2**

Is it possible to only have a qty of 1 in the cart for the same product? Like if I add a qty of 10 to the cart, it only adds 1 because its the same product.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to Magento 2 admin panel
2. Navigate to Stores > Settings > Configuration
3. Select Inventory under Catalog section
4. Expand Product Stock Options section
5. Set the maximum quantity as per your business requirement in Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
6. Click Save Config

[image]

Comment: This allows only 1 product of the same type in the cart ... what I need is a way to put as many in the cart as I want, but they still only count as 1.

Comment: it's not default. for that you need to do customization